# Why is gksu asking me for root password and not my password?

Tags: sudo, root, gentoo, authentication, gksu

On one of my systems, I'm running Gentoo Linux and I've installed `x11-libs/gksu-2.0.2-r1`. I've disabled the root account using `sudo passwd -dl root` and I want to be able to run GUI apps which need root privileges using `sudo`.

I've set `gksu` to use `sudo` for authentication using `gksu-properties`, but it's still asking me for *root* password when I launch an application that needs root privileges and not *mine*.

What am I missing?

Comment: `gksu` is also a Gtk+ frontend to `su`.  Looks like it is trying to run the `su` program.

Comment: @dr01 I'm telling `gksu` to use `sudo` for authentication, not `su` (see second paragraph of my question)

Comment: @MasterRoot24 you haven't set `targetpw` in sudoers, by any chance, have you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I worked out that even though I was setting `gksu` to use `sudo` for authentication, this was all irrelevant as the shortcuts that I was using in the Xfce menu were starting applications using `polkit` and not `gksu`.

From the [Gentoo Wiki on polkit](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Polkit#Rules), I did:

```
sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/10-admin.rules" <<EOL
polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {
    return ["unix-group:wheel"];
});
EOL
```

...and this let me start applications which needed root privileges by entering *my* password in sudo-style fashion.

Answer (score 4):

`gksu` acts like `su`, not `sudo`. That's why it asks you root password.

Try to run `gksudo` instead if available. If not, you can run `gksu --sudo-mode`.

Also, from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksu):

> Also notice that the library will decide if it should use su or sudo as backend using the /apps/gksu/sudo-mode gconf key, if you call the gksu command. You can force the backend by using the gksudo command, or by using the --sudo-mode and --su-mode options.

Comment: If `/apps/gksu/sudo-mode` is set to `true`, then `gksu` works like `sudo` and not `su`

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, just the wrong command.  Try:

1. Enable `sudo` by installing `app-admin/sudo`....Done
2. Configure `sudo` using visudo.  Set the appropriate options ....
   Hopefully Done
3. Use `gksudo app-name` instead of `gksu app-name`.

In gentoo, gksudo is part of the package `x11-libs/gksu`, and the actual man page is at [gksudo man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo).  As always make sure the gnome USE Flag is set.

Comment: Yeah, I've already installed `sudo` - see the first part of my question...